# Spring-Batch how to write job metdata in different database?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-boot

I'm using `Spring-Batch` to persist lots of data in a database using batch `JpaItemWriter<T>`.

I would like to have the job-metadata that is autogenerated by spring to be written into a different database (an `embedded h2` would be sufficient) than the data that is written by the ItemWriter.

Is that possible at all? Where would I have to set the different DataSource or TransactionManager so that the job-metadata gets persisted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that my configuration was already working, but spring-boot automatically loads them `schema-{db}.sql` scripts on startup. Thus I always had the metadata in my main DB.

Solution is a simple property:

`spring.batch.initializer.enabled=false`

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, but as soon as you create a second DataSource you're going to have to autowiring problems because Spring will start finding two candidate beans. Here's how you can get around this:

(1) Mark you current datasource bean with @Primary (you will need to create this bean explicitly if you're not already doing so)

```
    @Bean(name = "mainDataSource")
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource") //assuming connection, credentials configured in application.properties
    public DataSource createDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
```

(2) Create your new datasource (same as above) for you job meta-data, and give it a name.

(3) Use an @Qualifier to autowire this new datasource in the repository you use to persist your job meta-data.

Comment: Thanks I will try this. But: I'm using `MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean, MapJobExplorerFactoryBean, SimpleJobLauncher` (similar do `DefaultBatchConfigurer`. Where do I have to pass my custom metadata-db? because non of them takes a `DataSource` as argument...

Comment: Maybe I was also not concrete enough: I want the data to be persisted by the `JpaItemWriter` using spring batch, but the batch metadata that is written alongside the job execution should go instead to an h2.

Comment: I don't know the particulars of spring batch well enough to help you beyond the two-datasource configuration. Sorry.

Comment: probably you need a configuration for distribuited transaction